# how to use Expand command efficiently

Tags: performance-tuning, algebraic-manipulation

Recently I got in a problem and I will try to explain with a simple example. I have an expression which reads :

```
y = (10 + 2*x )/x;
```

Now I want to substitute 1/x -> 0 . Now if I substitute directly in this expression the result is zero i.e.

```
y = (10 + 2*x )/x;
y /. {1/x -> 0};
Print[y];
```

Answer = 0 which should not be.

So I have to expand before substituting i.e.

```
y = (10 + 2*x )/x;
y1=Expand[y,x];
y1 /. {1/x -> 0};
Print[y1];
```

which gives me the correct answer = 2.

My question is, is there any efficient way (or another way) to do this work. This is because in case of 'y' has a very large expression or coefficient of 1/x is very complicated, Expand command is taking very very long time.

Comment: What about taking the limit `x->Infinity` ?

Comment: Hi @Mher Safaryan , if you are suggesting not to use Expand and just to use y /. {x ->Infinity} , it won't work. The problem will be the same no? Previously it gave 0, now it will give Infinity.

Comment: Why it is infinity ? it's just 2 for your example. Just try this (* Limit[y, {x -> Infinity}] *)

Comment: I believe that @Mher was suggesting that you use `Limit[y, x -> Infinity]`, which does yield `2`.  So does `First@Collect[y, x]` or `Coefficient[y, x, 0]`.  The last may be best, depending on your goal.

Comment: okay both are working .. thank you both.

Comment: @Mher, please turn your comment into an answer so that this question can disappear from the "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to substitute `1/x->0` in in expressions then take the limit `x->Infinity`:

```
y = (10+2*x)/x;
Limit[y, x->Infinity]
```

Other ways of doing that is the followings (see bbgodfrey's comment):

```
First@Collect[y, x]
Coefficient[y, x, 0]
```